# How filter users in User Profile?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

How can I create column in SharePoint list to retrieve users from Active directory or user profile service filtered by department?

For example, if user select IT department this column will retrieve all employees at IT only.

Comment: why do you want to create a column in a list? Do you want to create items which match the filtered department? Can you please explain with an example?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that we cannot achieve your requirement in the list directly.

You could use search to retrieve users from user profile based on the Department.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[How to Build a Corporate Directory with SharePoint Search.](https://sharegate.com/blog/corporate-directory-sharepoint-search)

[Creating a Robust Employee Directory Using SharePoint Search.](https://help.insight.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/117/~/creating-a-robust-employee-directory-using-sharepoint-search)

Comment: This is fine but not what I mean. I need this functionality in list columns mean that I have custom list that has two columns Department and usernames as drop down columns.  when user select Sales as example from department column the usernames column populated with Sales employees only